# Silverlight 3 DataForm Control how to customize

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, customization, dataform

I am trying to use a silverlight 3 dataform in my project. But I need to bind different controls to different objects in this form. Is it possible to do that. I mean all the data need to fill and edit this form is not coming from one object. Is it achieveable?

I also want in my silverlight control to show a combobox when I bind it to a ObservableCollection. How can I do that?